# Present Perfect vs Present + Adjective

Tags: differences

What are the similarities and differences, for example, between "they are agreed" vs "they've agreed." Also, is there a formal grammatical term for the construct "they are agreed" ?

http://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/96405-We-are-agreed claims no differences:

> *In agreement* is simply a phrase that means having the same opinion.
>   *Agree*, as you use it, is an intransitive verb meaning to be in accord or having the same opinion.
>
> So, they are structurally different, but almost semantically the same. That is, they have the same meaning.
>   Yes, consensus has almost the same meaning, but its used in formal contexts.

Per contra, [this](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=843621&p=4527497#post4527497) DOES claim a difference:

> They "are" agreed is stative, they are in a state of agreement, and this doesn't necessarily mean that they spoke to each other and made the agreement, it might simply mean that **they have all taken the same position independently**. But when you say "they have agreed" it does imply that they have got together and agreed a position.

I'm contending against this latter argument. If **they have all taken the same position independently**, then haven't they agreed? Does it matter whether they acted alone or conferred?

[2 more examples here](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=843621&p=4528830#post4528830).

Comment: There may well be no semantic difference, even though there is a syntactic one; that is frequently the case with structures that resemble one another. In fact, that's part of the reason why they resemble one another; it's analogous to Müllerian mimicry in wasps and bees.

Comment: Yes, there are some interesting differences between the two versions: *"they are agreed",* and *"they have agreed"*.

Answer (score -1):

Personally this makes me feel like a change in time perspective.

*They are agreed* is an immediate situation.

*They have agreed* could be either immediate or some time in the past.

And from lepressentiment 'in agreement' is perfect as a formal term.

Hope this helps!